# Connecting a Dojo data.objectStore or data.ItemFileWriteStore to a grid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

I am trying to connect a dojo 1.7 objectStore or itemFileWriteStore to a grid but I;m not sure what I'm doing wrong.

When I run my code below using the ItemFileWriteStore, I get the grid headers but I dont see my data. When I use ObjectStore, the grid isnt there.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: just noticed that the store.data attribute is empty. Must mean the format of of my "dataBucket" could be wrong?

```
require(['dojo/on'
            ,'dojo/ready'
            ,'dojo/dom'
            ,"dojo/data/ObjectStore"
            ,"dojo/store/Memory"
            ,"dojox/grid/DataGrid"
            ,"dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore"
            ],
            function (on,ready,dom,objStore,memStore,grid,itemStore){
                ready(function(){
                    var dataBucket = {//idProperty: 'ID',  //for object store?
                                      identifer: 'ID', //for itemStore
                                      items : [
                                          {ID : '100', col2 : 'Ciao Ciao'},
                                          {ID : '200', col2 : 'Hello'}
                                      ]};

                    var stuff = new itemStore({data : dataBucket});
                    //var stuff = new objStore({store : dataBucket});
                    //var stuff = new memStore({data : dataBucket});

                    var layout = [[
                            {'name':'ID','field' : 'ID','width' : '100px'},
                            {'name':'Stuff','field' : 'col2','width' : '100px'}
                        ]];
                    var myGrid = new grid({
                                id: 'grid',
                                store: stuff,
                                structure: layout,
                                rowSelector: '20px'},
                            document.createElement('div')
                    );

                    dojo.byId("bottomPane").appendChild(myGrid.domNode);

                    myGrid.startup();                        })
                })
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out the store hadnt been populated with data correctly. It constructed a store without indicating the data passed in was in the incorrect format

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have made a mistake in `layout` definition. shouldn't second `field` be `col2`, like you defined in your `dataBucket` ?

Comment: its not that, I just tried to rename and it still doesnt work. I think its something to do with the store itself

Comment: try defining your `layout` without `'` surrounding `name`, `field` and `ID`: `{name: 'ID', field: 'ID', width: '100px'}`. it works this way for my grids.

Answer (score 0):

also you've write:

```
identifer: 'ID'
```

and it's

```
identifier: 'ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

The dojo/store/Memory go inner to dojo/store/ObjectStore

```
stuff = new ObjectStore({ objectStore:new Memory({ data: dataBucket }) });
```

and the store property of the grid

```
var myGrid = new grid({
                        id: 'grid',
                        store: stuff,
                        structure: layout,
                        rowSelector: '20px'},
                        document.createElement('div')
                    );
```